# No document about PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed documents for visual studio 2010, though online installing, which included `Win32 & Com, DDK, and SDK 7.1`, but when I lookup `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS`, it got no results, am I wrong ?

So I tried MSDN online, it got lot of pages related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a little helper type, the P makes it a pointer to the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure.  In other words, an alias for IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*.  The MSDN library doesn't document these wee ones.

Look up IMAGE_NT_HEADERS instead.

Comment: That worked, but I guess the indexes was somehow not perfect, if I lookup `IMAGE_NT_HEADER`, I got nothing for the ending `S`